# How can i add images into menu popup area

Tags: magento-1.9, image

I need add images into menu popup area,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Normally Magento will render the menu by block page/html_topmenu_renderer 
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer and templatefile at: default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml

You can use the renderer.phtml to add image into the magento's menu

For example: If I add this code:

```
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .' view-all">';
    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';



    ----Important here----
    if($counter == 1) {
        $html .= '<img src="http://www.9pager.com/content/images/2016/04/something-about-angularjs-scope-lifecycle.jpg" />';
    }
    ----Important here----



    $html .=             $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
    $html .=         '</a>';
    $html .=     '</li>';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

You will see something like:

[image: Add image to menu]

For example: If I change this code:

```
if($childLevel ==0 && $counter == 2) {
        $html .= '<img src="http://www.9pager.com/content/images/2016/04/something-about-angularjs-scope-lifecycle.jpg" />';
    }
```

I will get:

[image]

You see we now the picture occur in menu 2 because couter = 2. $childLevel = 0 here because in demo I want it occur in level 2. Now If you have three level and want it occur in level 3, change $childLevel = 1.

Comment: could please give any document or any other demo

Comment: To know location: Enable template hint. Read this:

http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Remember. You must choose  the: Current Configuration Scope. It is very important. If you don't choose. You will not see. Template Path Hints

Comment: i got the page renderer.phtml, can i copy the whole coding what you post, or just take with in tha tag ----Important here----

Comment: Depend on your location. You just need change two thing:

$childLevel and $counter

Comment: one moment, i will screen shots

Comment: first half : http://i.imgur.com/sSs3wl7.png

Comment: second half : http://i.imgur.com/SvfHvmn.png

Comment: how make i changes

Comment: The image show block class not template file: renderer.phtml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42237/discussion-between-virus-and-jeeva-rathinam).